# Change names of pages in wordpress

Tags: pages

I am inheriting a Wordpress site where the page names in URLs are very descriptive things like page_id=81. Is this something that I can change globally or do a simple search and replace on?

Comment: have a look at the [permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) info page in the codex.

Answer (score 1):

By default, WordPress uses a query variable structure for URLs because it doesn't know for sure whether or not your system supports URL rewriting.  But if your server *does* support rewriting, you can enable [Pretty Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Basically, pages change from `http://blog.url/?page_id=81` to `http://blog.url/page-slug`.  Posts change from `http://blog.url/?p=82` to `http://blog.url/2011/05/post-slug`.

You can adjust the settings to use whatever URL structure you need on the Permalinks page within WordPress.  So yes, it's something you can change globally.

Comment: And the nice thing is that the older URLs keep working and will redirect to the "pretty" URLs, so you don't need to worry about broken links.